# How do I achieve this in .net url routing?

Tags: .net, webforms, url-routing

I'm using .net routing for web forms.

I have 2 routes like this

1) route name = "recover", routeurl = "my-account/recover"
2) route name = "recover-verify", routeurl = "my-account/recover/{email}/{auth}"

Both go to the same page.

When I land on the page, need to check which route it is and then how/hide things accordingly.

However, when I do this:

```
var email = Page.RouteData.GetRequiredString("Email");
```

I get an exception on 1 rather than simply returning null for a later check.

How is it possible to determine which route is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

```
var emailAction = Page.RouteData.Values["email"];

if(emailAction != null){
    // Parameter is available
}
```